# transition between two map shape files

Tags: maps, d3.js

I have two map shape files. One is a geographic projection of the regions of the UK containing 28 polygons. The other is a geometric projection showing the same 28 regions but as simple squares. Both are geojson files. Is it posible to create a transition between the two so that the shapes tween from one to the other?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to do that using a simple `.transition()` with different `.data()` calls. Do you have a live example somewhere?

Comment: I'm afraid not at the moment as I'm just building the project in between other print graphics that I have to do. I'll get one online so people can check it out.

Comment: Here is an example of transitioning / morphing an area shape into a circle. 

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3081153